# How do I check that a single variable has multiple parameters populated

Tags: bash, shell, dockerfile

In a Dockerfile I have

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-DmyKeyStore=${blah1} -DmyApi=${blah2} -Dsalt=${blah3}"
```

The `${blah}` variables are populated during our CI/CD run but I want the Docker build to fail if one of the parameters fails to get populated.

I can use the below code to check if `ENV JAVA_OPTS` as a whole isn't populated.

`RUN if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then echo 'Environment variable JAVA_OPTS must be specified. Exiting.'; exit 1; fi`

but I want to do a deeper check within that variable and fail if `-DmyKeyStore=blank/null` for example.

Comment: (Good first Q!) The shell has a feature built in that will perform this for you. Whether it will give you the results you need inside of your docker environment will have to be to your testing. You can use `${blah1:?Blah1_Var_Not_Set}` where the string after `:?` can be anything you want. It also (in a shell context) exits the current command with a false return code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `docker` uses bash, and not something internal?  If it uses bash, then you could always use the `${param:?message}` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to generate an error.

Something like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-DmyKeyStore=${blah1:?} -DmyApi=${blah2:?} -Dsalt=${blah3:?}"
```

You can test it in an interactive shell like this:

```bash
$ : ${t:?}
bash: t: parameter null or not set
$ t=1
$ : ${t:?}
```